# PHP: UPS API Tracking

Tags: php, api, ups

I'm having a lot of trouble tracking packages using UPS api. I don't understand how it works, I downloaded these file from UPS examples:

```
$wsdl = " Add Wsdl File Here ";
$endpointurl = ' Add URL Here';
```

I don't have any wsdl file and when I downloaded the UPS tracking example, there weren't any. I also don't know what to put for the end point url. UPS doesn't explain, or at least I cannot find where they do.

So then I decided to try this:

https://github.com/gabrielbull/php-ups-api#installation

But I have not idea on how to use it. I have downloaded the files, but I don't know where I can put my test file:

```
$tracking = new Ups\Tracking($accessKey, $userId, $password);

try {
    $shipment = $tracking->track('TRACKING NUMBER');

    foreach($shipment->Package->Activity as $activity) {
        var_dump($activity);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

And I don't know where to put my credentials for API Access key, username and password either. I am very confused now and I can't figure out anything. I'm sorry for my bad english. Thank you.

Here is my full code from UPS:

```
  //Configuration
  $access = "XXX";
  $userid = "XXX";
  $passwd = "XXX";
  $wsdl = " Add Wsdl File Here ";
  $operation = "ProcessTrack";
  $endpointurl = ' Add URL Here';
  $outputFileName = "XOLTResult.xml";

  function processTrack()
  {
      //create soap request
    $req['RequestOption'] = '15';
    $tref['CustomerContext'] = 'Add description here';
    $req['TransactionReference'] = $tref;
    $request['Request'] = $req;
    $request['InquiryNumber'] = '';
    $request['TrackingOption'] = '02';

    echo "Request.......\n";
    print_r($request);
    echo "\n\n";
    return $request;
  }

  try
  {

    $mode = array
    (
         'soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  // use soap 1.1 client
         'trace' => 1
    );

    // initialize soap client
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl , $mode);

    //set endpoint url
    $client->__setLocation($endpointurl);


    //create soap header
    $usernameToken['Username'] = $userid;
    $usernameToken['Password'] = $passwd;
    $serviceAccessLicense['AccessLicenseNumber'] = $access;
    $upss['UsernameToken'] = $usernameToken;
    $upss['ServiceAccessToken'] = $serviceAccessLicense;

    $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0','UPSSecurity',$upss);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);


    //get response
    $resp = $client->__soapCall($operation ,array(processTrack()));

    //get status
    echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";

    //save soap request and response to file
    $fw = fopen($outputFileName , 'w');
    fwrite($fw , "Request: \n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n");
    fwrite($fw , "Response: \n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "\n");
    fclose($fw);

  }
  catch(Exception $ex)
  {
    print_r ($ex);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The track WSDL is located in Tracking>TrackingPackage>TrackingWebServices>Schemas-WSDLs

You need to substitute your credentials in $access, $userid, $passwd and set the endpoint to the UPS test servers.

```
  $access = "XXX";
  $userid = "XXX";
  $passwd = "XXX";
  $wsdl = " Add Wsdl File Here ";
  $operation = "ProcessTrack";
  $endpointurl = ' Add URL Here';
```

Comment: What is the $enpointurl supposed to be?

Comment: @PeteNorth https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Track is the prod URL